# How to get element Id inside repeater control in ASpx page using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have done some searching on this but i can't seem to find anything related to my issue but how do i get the element Id inside a repeater control? for example i have the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><%# Eval("Name") %>
        <asp:HyperLink  ID="Url" runat="server" Text ="<%# Eval("Url") %>"/>  </span></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Behind the code i want to get and set Id (url) of the hyper link in code above but for some reason i can't access behind the code as it is not recognised. what is the best way to get the Id?

in my c# code , i just want to set url like so:
Url.NavigateUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com';

edit

now it doesn't hit the code inside the foreach loop.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Rpt.Items)
{
   HyperLink Url = item.FindControl("Url") as HyperLink;
   Url.NavigateUrl = link from db;
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: What code did you write for this? Without seeing code we can't tell what wrong you are doing.

Comment: show me your code where you want to get the id of repeater. Is this in C#? vb? jquery?

Comment: sorry C#..forgot to mention.. please see edit

Comment: I have answer it please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find using following ways:

Using ItemDataBound event:

```
protected void Rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {    
       HyperLink  hplUrl = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("Url");
       hplUrl.NavigateUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com'; 
    }
}
```

Or using all rows

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Rpt.Items)
{
   HyperLink Url = item.FindControl("Url") as HyperLink;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks.. could there by any reason why it doesn't hit the code inside the foreach loop?  could i be missing anything? please see edit

Comment: You need to call this `foreach` loop after `databind` of repeater control, otherwise it will overwrite it

Comment: But I suggest to use `ItemDataBound` event to set url from db

Answer (score 0):

below code can help you:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Rpt.Items)
{
   HyperLink lnk = item.FindControl("Url") as HyperLink;
}
```